# In voyager admin panel how to solve directory separator issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, voyager

I have created a page in the voyager admin panel, but when I tried to retrieve in view the path of the image is like

> http://localhost:8000/storage/pages\October2019\eltiRUSN1BArKdXi4uyl.png

you noticed that the first forward slash and then next backward slash, so that's why an image is not displaying in view.

I used this code to print an image.

```
<div class="header_bg" style="background-image: url('{{ url("storage/$page_data->image") }}');"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, this image is set by voyage admin so I have use voyager language.

```
<div class="header_bg" style="background-image: url('{{Voyager::image($page_data->image)}}');"></div>
```

to the print image which set from voyager in blade view use this syntax

```
{{Voyager::image($page_data->image)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a url with url(), maybe you could use Laravel File Storage helpers, like `Storage::get('file.jpg');`. I believe these work in blade, so in your case, it would be:

```
<div class="header_bg" style="background-image: url('{{ Storage::get($page_data->image) }}');"></div>
```

Comment: this not solve my issue. It gets only  pages\October2019\eltiRUSN1BArKdXi4uyl.png   path

before that is missing

but thanks for answer.